# calculate number of weeks in a given year

Tags: java, android, calendar

I would like to get the number of weeks in any given year. Even though `52` is accepted as a generalised worldwide answer, the calendars for `2015`, `2020` and `2026` actually have `53` weeks.

Is there any way that I can calculate this, or any functions that will help me out?

Comment: General comment for all which doesn't exactly answer the question above but is useful to know: To understand why the Calendar class returns 53 for "number of weeks in a year" you have to understand how the `getFirstDayOfWeek()` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` methods are used in the calculation. If the "first day of the week" is specified as Monday for example and the "minimal days in first week" is 4 and the first Monday of the year is on 5th January, then the week preceding 5th January is classed as part of that year.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the wikipedia article on [ISO week date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation), You can calculate it using following code.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);

    int ordinalDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1; // Sunday = 0
    int numberOfWeeks = (ordinalDay - weekDay + 10) / 7;
    System.out.println(numberOfWeeks);
```

---

**Update:**

Seems the answer from @Samuel https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174287/201986 is better and free from the bug mentioned by Luca

Comment: thanx Manjula. Somehow my problem was fixed automatically. I think Calendar class doesnt consider week 53. (no idea, what Date format it follows...). But          calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 52);
     calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMM yyyy");
     Date startDate = calendar.getTime();
     calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
     Date endDate = calendar.getTime();
gives me start & end date for week as 27 Dec2015 & 2nd Jan2016. :) :)  (these dates i was expecting for week 53, which was the reason for this question thread.. :)  )

Comment: This actually introduce a bug. I just tried it out: for 2016, it return 52, but Calendar consider it having 53 weeks. It actually has 53 weeks because it start with a Thursday. I review your function: I'll post it down below. Please edit your answer in order to remove this bug :)

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal this was answered in 2012 (8 years ago :O ). anyway I updated the post to link to current best answer.

Comment: I need it in java 8

Answer (score 15):

Quick one liner:

```
Integer weeksOfYear = Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: It would have been nice to see a more detailed explanation of this method. `getActualMaximum` iteratively counts the total number based on current time, whereas `getMaximum` just returns the maximum value of that field. So `getActualMaximum` is indeed the answer to this question.

Answer (score 10):

You can code yourself with the following information from [ISO week date.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

**On average, a year has 53 weeks every 5.6 years.**

> The following 71 years in a 400-year cycle (add 2000 for current years) have 53 weeks. Years not listed have 52 weeks.
>
> 004, 009, 015, 020, 026, 032, 037, 043, 048, 054, 060, 065, 071, 076, 082, 088, 093, 099, 105, 111, 116, 122, 128, 133, 139, 144, 150, 156, 161, 167, 172, 178, 184, 189, 195, 201, 207, 212, 218, 224, 229, 235, 240, 246, 252, 257, 263, 268, 274, 280, 285, 291, 296, 303, 308, 314, 320, 325, 331, 336, 342, 348, 353, 359, 364, 370, 376, 381, 387, 392, 398.

You can use the above information to return 52 or 53 accordingly :)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to give my take on usage of the new Date API in Java 8 with the following ready to run code:

```
private static long getNumberOfWeeksInYear(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate middleOfYear = date.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonth(6);
    return middleOfYear.range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()).getMaximum();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int year = 2000; year < 2400; year++) {
        long numberOfWeeks = getNumberOfWeeksInYear(LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1));
        if (numberOfWeeks != 52) {
            System.out.println(year + " has " + numberOfWeeks + " weeks");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

> 2004 has 53 weeks
>  2009 has 53 weeks
>  2015 has 53 weeks
>   2020 has 53 weeks
>  2026 has 53 weeks
>  2032 has 53 weeks
> ...

And so on...

The `date.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonth(6);` trick is because omitting this results in slightly different output if `LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1)` is passed:

> 2004 has 53 weeks
>  2005 has 53 weeks
> ...

I am still new to the Java 8 date API, but my I am pretty sure this behaviour is becuase 2005-01-01 is part of week 53 of 2014. This makes `date.range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()).getMaximum()` return the number of weeks for the week based year of 2014.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Comment: It doesn't work in every year. Even your example does return "1" instead of 53.

Comment: But it is a week 01. Week number is defined in ISO-8601. Week 1 is the one with the first thursday of the year in it.

Answer (score 2):

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952468/2163045)

```
gregorianCalendar.set(year, 12, 31);
int totalWeeks = gregorianCalendar.getMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Manjula Weerasinge answer actually introduce a bug for 2016. Here's a better solution.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();

int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
if (gregorianCalendar.isLeapYear(year)){
   if (weekDay == Calendar.THURSDAY || weekDay == Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
      return 53;
   else
      return 52;
} else {
   if (weekDay == Calendar.THURSDAY)
      return 53;
   else
      return 52;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method calculates the number of weeks a ISO year using the Joda time library.

```
    import org.joda.time.DateTime;
    import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

    public static int weeksInYear(int year) {
        return new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"))
            .withWeekyear(year + 1)
            .withWeekOfWeekyear(1)
            .minusWeeks(1)
            .getWeekOfWeekyear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For ISO date format, we can calculate number of weeks as follows:

```
int getNoOfWeeks(int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

So, for year = 2018, it will return 52, for 2019, it will also return 52, but for 2020 it will return 53 as ISO year has 52 or 53 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

According to ISO standards, a week starts on a Monday and the first week of the year is the week with the first Thursday of the year.

Following this logic, **28th of December** always lies in the last week of the year.

```java
long maxWeekInYear(int year) {
    return LocalDate.of(year, 12, 28).get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
}
```

However, some countries have other definitions of a week. The `WeekFields` class allows one to use a given definition of a week:

```java
long maxWeekInYear(int year, WeekFields weekFields) {
    return LocalDate.of(year, 7, 1).range(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear()).getMaximum();
}
```

For instance, in the US, a week starts on Sunday and the minimum number of days in the first week of the year is 4. `WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 4)` can be used to determine the number of weeks according to US rules. This is consistent with the results from [Savvytime.com](https://savvytime.com/week-number/united-states/2031).