# Android ThreeTenAbp get all weeks of the year to array

Tags: android, date, android-calendar

So I'm trying to load all weeks of the year using [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/) library, but I have no idea where to start because there is no documentation. At least I couldn't find any. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) is just an Android-specific adaptation of the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) Java project.

[*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) is a back-port of the Java SE 8 date-time classes (*java.time*) to Java SE 6 and 7. You can find its documentation [here](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/index.html).

Code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27133400/1401164):

```java
private static long getNumberOfWeeksInYear(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate middleOfYear = date.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonth(6);
    return middleOfYear.range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()).getMaximum();
}
```

And you can call it passing the following parameter:

```java
LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1) // replace year by the the year you want, e.g. 2009
```

Comment: Correct Answer, but you should point them to the class [JavaDoc of *ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/index.html) rather than the *java.time* classes. While the back-port has *most* of the *java.time* functionality, it does not have *all*. There are a few differences.

Comment: Add a link to the Question, [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks Basil, just edited the answer pointing to the correct javadoc. That's a great answer from the link above, thanks for that too!