# 4-4-5 Calendar approach based on Java 8 Code

Tags: java, excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

For my Fiscal Calendar in Power BI I am currently trying to implement the [4-4-5 approach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar).

Our calendar works with 4-4-5 week quarters. Since this only has 364 days each year, there must be a 53 week year after a few years. As a result, December has 6 instead of 5 weeks.
Unfortunately, there is still no approach based on DAX.
In another post here, however, I found a JAVA code, which probably determines whether the year has 53 weeks or not:
[calculate number of weeks in a given year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723862/calculate-number-of-weeks-in-a-given-year/40174287#40174287)

```
    private static long getNumberOfWeeksInYear(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate middleOfYear = date.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonth(6);
    return middleOfYear.range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()).getMaximum();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int year = 2000; year < 2400; year++) {
        long numberOfWeeks = getNumberOfWeeksInYear(LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1));
        if (numberOfWeeks != 52) {
            System.out.println(year + " has " + numberOfWeeks + " weeks");
        }
    }
}
```

Do any of you know how to translate the code into Dax?

Our Fiscal Calendar starts not based on the gregorian calendar.
This year starts at 30.12.19 and ends 03.01.21. This year has 53 weeks.

Comment: For 4-4-5 accounting calendar implementation in Java, see `AccountingChronology` and `AccountingChronologyBuilder` ([Javadoc](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html)) in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help with `PowerPivot` and `DAX`. But I can tell you how to get those information using`Excel` formulas.

Given the year in `A2` you can calculate the Monday of the first `ISO` calendar week in that year using following formula:

```
=DATE($A2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A2,1,1),3)+(ISOWEEKNUM(DATE($A2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A2,1,1),3))<>1)*7
```

You can calculate the Sunday of the last `ISO` calendar week in that year using following formula:

```
=DATE($A2+1,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A2+1,1,1),3)+(ISOWEEKNUM(DATE($A2+1,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A2+1,1,1),3))<>1)*7-1
```

Given the Sunday of the last `ISO` calendar week placed in `C2`, following formula calculates the number of `ISO` weeks of that year:

```
=ISOWEEKNUM($C2)
```

Example:

[image]

As you see, the years are from `A2` downwards. Formula to calculate the Monday of the first `ISO` calendar week is placed in `B2` downwards. Formula to calculate the Sunday of the last `ISO` calendar week is in `C2` downwards. And the formula to calculate the number of `ISO` weeks of that year is in `D2` downwards.

Comment: Thanks for that awesome approach! It works perfectly. How would you calculate the fiscal week for each date in a calendar table based on these information?

Comment: @joshua: This is not how Stackoverflow works. If you have a new question then ask a new question. If this is a follow up question to another question the do referencing that other question in your new question. And please be more verbose in your question. What is a fiscal week for you compared to a calendar week? What calendar table are you talking about? And what means "based on these information" in that context? Best way is providing what you have, what you have tried, what was the result of that and what are you expecting to be the result.